# How to check if a KQL query returns null or not in Power Automate

Tags: azure, power-automate, azure-data-explorer, kql

In Power Automate I am running a KQL query titled 'cmdletsForEmail' using the action 'Run KQL Query'. The query returns a row with a couple of columns if there is a problem.

I try to check if the query body is empty using this:

```
empty(body('cmdletsForEmail')?['value'])
```

in this condition

[image]

However, it is always evaluated to False even if there are rows returned.
{
"expressionResult": false
}

How can I change the condition to check if the query returns no rows?

Here is a screenshot of the condition:
[image: condition screenshot]

I also tried this value for the condition but now it always resolves as true:

```
empty(outputs('cmdletsForEmail')?['body/body'])
```

But then the condition always returns true.
The Condition json input is:
{
"expressionResult": true
}

**Attempted Solutions:**
The Run KQL Query action in my Flow is returning an Html Table.

The output of the Run KQL Query action is (edited for brevity):

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Set-Cookie": "…",
        "x-ms-request-id": "…",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=’…’; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
        "x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",
        "Date": "Wed, 08 Mar 2023 16:28:20 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Expires": "-1",
        "Content-Length": "5487"
    },
    "body": {
        "attachmentName": "kusto_flow_table_...",
        "attachmentContent": "…",
        "body": "…",
        "bodyHtml": "<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"1\" bordercolor=\"Black\" style=\"font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;;font-size:12px;border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr bgcolor=\"DarkGray\"><td nowrap=\"nowrap\">Command</td><td nowrap=\"nowrap\">failRateCurrentRounded</td><td nowrap=\"nowrap\">failRateLastWeekRounded</td><td nowrap=\"nowrap\">failRateLastWeekPercent</td><td nowrap=\"nowrap\">failRateCurrentPercent</td><td nowrap=\"nowrap\">generateEmail</td></tr></table><a href=’<kusto cluster link>’ style='color:green; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 8pt;'>’<Kusto cluster link>’</a> [<a href=’kusto cluster and database and query link' style='color:blue; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 8pt;'>Open on Web</a>] [<a href=’kusto cluster and query link’ style='color:blue; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 8pt;'>Open on Desktop</a>]",
        "kustoDeepLink": "<a href=’kusto cluster link' style='color:green; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 8pt;'>Kusto cluster link</a> [<a href=’kusto cluster and query link' style='color:blue; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 8pt;'>Open on Web</a>] [<a href=’kusto cluster and query link’ style='color:blue; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 8pt;'>Open on Desktop</a>]"
    }
}
```

I tried changing the condition to check if
length(outputs('cmdletsForEmail')?['body/body']) is not equal to 0, however this resulted in an email sent with an empty table.

I tried changing the condition to check if
length(outputs('cmdletsForEmail')?['body']) is not equal to 0, but that resulted in an error stating

> Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition_2' at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#length for usage details.'.

I tried changing the condition to check if
length(outputs('cmdletsForEmail')?['body/value']) is not equal to 0 but that resulted in an error stating

> Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition_2' at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#length for usage details.'.

Comment: empty(...) **is equal to** true

Comment: Show us the resulting JSON for both instances (i.e. true and false) and we can go from there

Comment: @Skin, done. See above.

Comment: No, I mean the JSON in and out of the KQL query step, not the IF statement.  That doesn't help me at all.  :-)

Comment: @Skin, yeah, I was confused about that, sorry. I added the KQL output above.

Comment: Ok, just so I'm clear (because I'm yet to use it) does the KQL query connector return a HTML table of data and in the example you've given, you have no records returned, is that correct?  If that is the case, I may need a small example that shows a response with records returned, just so I'm clear on the output.  I'm 99% sure it won't be an issue to work with what you've provided so far but I want to be sure when working with a response that does have records.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to check whether query returned any rows or not.

```
length(outputs('Run_KQL_query')?['body/value'])
```

**Explanation:-**
The KQL query in power automate returns output in json object format and **value** is an array property of the json object which holds collection of rows returned by the query. Please refer same [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/What-is-difference-between-value-and-body-from-Get-Items/td-p/666706#:%7E:text=The%20output%20of%20body%20is,get%20items%20as%20their%20inputs.).

Using `length()` we can check whether the **value** array is empty or has any value. If array is empty then code mentioned above will return **0** else it will return number of records.

**Screenshots for sample run**

[Condition checking the length of value array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfF5n.png)

[Query returning records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Y7U.png)

[Query returning no records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFqgC.png)

Comment: That did not work @RitikaNalwaya , I updated my response above with the details.

Comment: @AdamS can you please share the screenshot of the condition and pre and post actions in the logic app.

Comment: I added the screenshot above. Hope it helps.